# Backspace character does not work in the Go playground

Tags: go, control-characters, go-playground

I am new to Go. Just learnt the various uses of `fmt.Println()`. I tried the following stuff [in the official playground](https://play.golang.com/p/V1GF4Afzy1Q) but got a pretty unexpected output. Please explain where I have gone wrong in my understanding.

input: `fmt.Println("hi\b", "there!")`  
output: `hi� there!`  
expected: `h there!`

input: `fmt.Println("hi", '\b', "there!")`  
output: `hi 8 there!`  
expected: `hithere!`... assuming runes are not appended with spaces

input: `fmt.Println("hi", "\bthere!")`  
output: `hi �there!`  
expected: `hithere!`

---

(Note: above, the placeholder character has been substituted by U+FFFD, as the original character does not render consistently between environments.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program outputs exactly what you told it to.  The problem is mostly with your output viewer.

Control characters and sequences only have their expected effect when sent to a compatible virtual console (or a physical terminal, or a printer or teletypewriter; but the latter are pretty rare these days).  What the Go playground does is capture the output of your program as-is and send it unmodified to the browser to display.  The browser does not interpret terminal control codes (other than the newline character, and even that only sometimes); instead, it expects formatting to be conveyed via HTML markup.  Since the backspace character does not have an assigned glyph, browsers will usually display a placeholder glyph instead, or sometimes nothing at all.

You would get a similar effect if, when running your Go program on your local machine, you redirected its output into a text file and then opened the file in a text editor: the editor will not interpret any escape sequence contained in the text file; sometimes it will even actively prevent control characters from being interpreted by the terminal displaying the editor (if it happens to be console-based editor), by substituting a symbolic, conventional representation of the character like `^H`.

In the middle example, the `'\b'` literal evaluates to an integer with the value of the character’s Unicode code point number (what Go terms a ‘rune’).  This is [explained in the specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Rune_literals):

> A rune literal represents a rune constant, an integer value identifying a Unicode code point. A rune literal is expressed as one or more characters enclosed in single quotes, as in `'x'` or `'\n'`. Within the quotes, any character may appear except newline and unescaped single quote. A single quoted character represents the Unicode value of the character itself, while multi-character sequences beginning with a backslash encode values in various formats.

Since `'\b'` represents U+0008, what is passed to `fmt.Println` is the integer value 8.  The function then prints the integer as its decimal representation, instead of interpreting it as a character code.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check out is your terminal, '\b' is terminal dependent, check if the terminal running your program handles that as "move cursor one character back" (most unixes-like will, i don't know about Windows), your first and third given example works exactly how your expectation is on my terminal (st).

> input: fmt.Println("hi", '\b', "there!")
>
> output: hi 8 there!
>
> expected: hithere!... assuming runes are not appended with spaces

Here your assumption is not what package [fmt](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#section-documentation) does:

> For each Printf-like function, there is also a Print function that takes no format and is equivalent to saying %v for every operand. Another variant Println inserts blanks between operands and appends a newline.

Fmt handles `%v` for rune as `%d`, not `%c`, so '\b' is formatted as "8" (ascii value 56), not the '\b' (ascii value 8). Also runes will have a space if they are between two arguments.

What Println does for this input is:

`print string "hi"`

`print space`

`format number 8 then print string "8"`

`print space`

`print string "there!"`

To debug problems like rendering invisible characters, I suggest you to use `encoding/hex` package, For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    d := hex.Dumper(os.Stdout)
    defer d.Close()

    fmt.Fprintln(d, "hi", '\b', "there!")
}
```

Output: `00000000  68 69 20 38 20 74 68 65  72 65 21 0a              |hi 8 there!.|`
Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/F-I2mdh43K7